# How to limit the number of messages sent through a mail server?

Tags: email, smtp

I am running a small server on a LAN and do not expect more than a couple dozen emails an hour or so.  A user on the LAN accidentally set off a few thousand emails at once.  Is there a tool or setting (using exim4, but any popular open source MTA available on Ubuntu will do) that could temporarily block such episodes or at least send a notification so that the excitement can be contained?

Nothing came up in a quick search, so even useful search terms would be helpful as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For exim4, you're looking for ACL [ratelimit settings](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch42.html#SECTratelimiting) (although some mailers put it under 'policy')